What connector/fix for garbage disposal plumbing?
I bought my home a few years ago, no problems. Lately when I run the garbage disposal the dirty water will spew out of this gap between the pipes. It looks improperly connected (it's not connected, the black pipe was just shoved inside the white).
Can someone advise how to fix this? I've tried plumbers putty around the gap but it didn't hold.


You need a a tailpiece and gasket kit for 1.5" pipes.   You need three parts.    You need a tailpiece - straight piece to get down further, you need a screwtop for that piece and a rubber gasket for the screwtop.
You can also cut the L pipe you have at the bottom to give you a little extra room.   In your picture I do NOT see a ptrap.   If you do not have one, replace the bottom elbow and install a ptrap.

I do have a p trap, it's just off to the side. Here's a picture of the whole set-up. There's not a ton of room at the moment, do I have to re-do the garbage disposal side to make it function properly? I was hoping there would be a coupling or something similar to properly attach the 2 pieces. https://i.imgur.com/quRxLVt.jpeg

That looks pretty good.   I would want a tiny slope down going to the T.

You need a 1 1/2" slip-joint extension:

